# How can I use a submit button inside a PHP variable to store to the db?

Tags: php, mysql, post, if-statement, isset

I am trying to store a variable in a database when the user clicks the submit button. However, as my submit button is inside of a PHP variable when I am using `isset`, it doesn't work. Is there another solution or a trick to that?

```
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<form id="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input name="terms"  type="checkbox" required value="agree" form="paypal"  /><label>Agree with terms & Conditions *</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="changebutton" value="ΕΠΙΒΕΒΑΙΩΣΗ ΠΑΡΑΓΓΕΛΙΑΣ"  /></form>';

 if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
//update orders to accept terms
$updatesql=mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET terms='agree' WHERE checkout_id='$checkout_id'") or die(mysql_error());  }
```

Comment: That form posts to `paypal.com`, you will never see the request. Check the PayPal developer manual on how to integrate it with your site.

Comment: exactly what you want to save in to the database?

Comment: Unless you echo or print $pp_checkout_btn, it doesn't exist in the HTML document. I didn't see an echo or print.

Answer (score 2):

First of all double check your 'action' in the form if it's correct and your if isset statement has to look like this:
    `if(isset($_POST['submit1']))` because form method is POST

Answer (score 1):

you can call an js function at onsubmit event in ur form. In your function send an ajax request to a PHP page that saves the data u need to save.

I am assuming ur echoing the variable in a HTML page.

```
<form id="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()" name="paypal" >
<input name="terms"  type="checkbox" required value="agree" form="paypal"  /><label>Agree with terms & Conditions *</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="changebutton" value="ΕΠΙΒΕΒΑΙΩΣΗ ΠΑΡΑΓΓΕΛΙΑΣ"  /></form>'
```

now the function:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
var str= document.forms["paypal"]["terms"].value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "save.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

now save.PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
 //your update query  
 }
  ?>
```